# MinGW: Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 2.4.0+ and MPC 0.8.0+

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw, gnu, msys

I am attempting to build GCC-5.3.0 on a PC running Windows 10 with MinGW software.
I got this error

```
configure: error: Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 2.4.0+ and MPC 
0.8.0+.
Try the --with-gmp, --with-mpfr and/or --with-mpc options to specify
their locations.  Source code for these libraries can be found at
their respective hosting sites as well as at
ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/.  See also
http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html for additional info.  If
you obtained GMP, MPFR and/or MPC from a vendor distribution package,
make sure that you have installed both the libraries and the header
files.  They may be located in separate packages.
```

My input was

```
username@computername /d/gnu/gcc-5.3.0-build
$ ../gcc-5.3.0/configure --target arm-eabi --enable-win32-registry=My
ToolchainName --prefix /f/gnu/out/ --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable
-nls --disable-shared --with-newlib --with-headers=../newlib-2.4.0/ne
wlib/libc/include
```

*Note: /d/ path as my D:/ drive*

I have added the path in environment variables

```
D:\MinGW\bin
```

I already installed libgmp 5.1.2, libmpfr 3.1.2, and libmpc 1.0.2 from MinGW installation manager

I followed the guide from http://gnutoolchains.com/building/ to build my own GNU toolchains on Windows

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory: you need to provide paths to required libraries via `--with-*` option, like `--with-gmp=/d/path/to/gmp`.

Comment: Thanks. i already found out that i do not have gmp.h file so i had to build my own GMP

Comment: Moved my comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download more library package build and install them into a new folder for example /c/gnu/install

```
gmp-6.1.2.tar.bz2
mpfr-3.1.5.tar.bz2
mpc-1.0.2.tar.gz
```

1> Build gmp

```
cd gmp-6.1.2
configure --prefix=/c/gnu/install/
make -j4 install
```

2> Build mpfr

```
cd mpfr-3.1.5
configure --prefix=/c/gnu/install/ --with-gmp=/c/gnu/install/ --enable-static --disable-shared
make -j4 install
```

3> Build mpc

```
cd mpc-1.0.2
configure --prefix=/c/gnu/install/ --with-gmp=/c/gnu/install/ --with-mpfr=/c/gnu/install/ --enable-static --disable-shared
make -j4 install
```

Then you configure building gcc with options :

```
--with-gmp=/c/gnu/install/ --with-mpfr=/c/gnu/install/ --with-mpc=/c/gnu/install/
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self-explanatory: you need to provide paths to required libraries via `--with-*` option, like `--with-gmp=/d/path/to/gmp`.